# Spring boot batch : How to run job with job parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I had to set jobparemeters on spring batch but with spring boot batch there is no way to do that easily.

I need to rerun job but if parameters are the same, spring-batch won't run again a job. So I decided to add a timestamp as parameter.

Comment: You can add the timestamp at launch time. See my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way and put my solution on stackoverflow for those that might be interested.

First you need to add this property on your application.properties / application.yml :

```
spring.batch.job.enabled: false
```

With that property spring boot doesn't run the job automatically.

Next, on your configuration file, you have to add a bean which runs your job and where you can put jobparameters :

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public JobExecution run(Job job, JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
    JobExecution jobExecution = null;
    try {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();

        jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        logger.info("Exit Status : " + jobExecution.getStatus());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jobExecution;
}
```

If you have a better way, let me know.

Comment: What about `java -jar myjob.jar param1=value1 param2=value2 time=$(date)` for example? With this, you don't need the code above.

Comment: In my case I think it works. But implementation depends of my OS. I will try.

Comment: Sure `$(date)` is for unix/linux, but you got the idea. You can do the same with a similar command of your OS to add the timestamp as a parameter in the command without the need to write the code above.